# Developing supporting services for a webservice

Tags: web-services, soa

How to develop **supporting services** for a webservice to monitor the performance of the service and to diagnose the services by means of monitoring the users, memory, database etc.,

Please provide some pointers for developing such services.

Thanks,

Velmurugan R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at JMX / MBeans. Mbeans can be used to read attributes from a running system in a standardized way. Or to invoke operations. With JConsole (distributed with Oracle JDK) you can connect to a running JVM and check out all existing MBeans.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/standard.html